# $a^{(p-1)/n}=1$ implies $b^n=a$ for some $b\in\mathbb F_p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, cyclic-groups

> Let $p$ be a prime. Let $n$ be a positive integer dividing $p-1$. 
>   Suppose that $a^{(p-1)/n}=1$ in the finite field $\mathbb F_p$ with exactly $p$ elements. Then does there exist $b$ with $a=b^n$?

Of course if there exists such an element $b$ then $a^{(p-1)/n}=1$ by Fermat little theorem.

Comment: Are you assuming here that $n$ is a divisor of $p-1,$ making $(p-1)/n$ an integer? Otherwise what is your definition of fractional powers in $F_p?$

Comment: Thank you. I should have written the assumption clearly.

Comment: Tim, it is not too late to add the assumption $n\mid p-1$. Why don't you do it? Click the *edit*-button below your post, and fix things! You should not assume that passers-by read this comment thread under the main post. This is in small print for a reason. Your job is to make the post as clear as possible.

Comment: Also, welcome to Math.SE! My recommendation to all users is to spend some time browsing the questions with tags that interest you. You will quickly learn more about how the site is organized, and what is expected from askers.

Comment: Thank you for your kind suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiplicative group of $\Bbb F_p$ is cylic (this is not obvious, but it is a well-known result). Say that $g$ is a generator. Then $a=g^k$ for some $k$. Now $a^{(p-1)/n}=1$ implies
$$g^{\frac kn(p-1)}=1$$
but since $g$ is a generator, $\frac kn(p-1)$ is a multiple of $p-1$, that is, $n$ divides $k$. Or $k=dn$.

Finally, $a=g^k=g^{dn}=(g^d)^n$. Put $b=g^d$ and you are done.

Comment: $a^{(p-1)/n}=1$ cannot be true if $a=0$, unless you work in $\{0\}$, in which case the theorem is also true

Comment: Thank you very much. I understood your gentle answer.